# Pytorch ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, backpropagation

When trying to create a neural network and optimize it using Pytorch, I am getting

> ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list

Here is the code.

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from os.path import dirname
from os import getcwd
from os.path import realpath
from sys import argv

class NetActor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args, state_vector_size, action_vector_size, hidden_layer_size_list):
        super(NetActor, self).__init__()
        self.args = args

        self.state_vector_size = state_vector_size
        self.action_vector_size = action_vector_size
        self.layer_sizes = hidden_layer_size_list
        self.layer_sizes.append(action_vector_size)

        self.nn_layers = []
        self._create_net()

    def _create_net(self):
        prev_layer_size = self.state_vector_size
        for next_layer_size in self.layer_sizes:
            next_layer = nn.Linear(prev_layer_size, next_layer_size)
            prev_layer_size = next_layer_size
            self.nn_layers.append(next_layer)

    def forward(self, torch_state):
        activations = torch_state
        for i,layer in enumerate(self.nn_layers):
            if i != len(self.nn_layers)-1:
                activations = F.relu(layer(activations))
            else:
                activations = layer(activations)

        probs = F.softmax(activations, dim=-1)
        return probs
```

and then the call

```
        self.actor_nn = NetActor(self.args, 4, 2, [128])
        self.actor_optimizer = optim.Adam(self.actor_nn.parameters(), lr=args.learning_rate)
```

gives the very informative error

> ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list

I find it hard to understand what exactly in the network's definition makes the network have parameters.

I am following and expanding the example I found in [Pytorch's tutorial code](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/reinforcement_learning/reinforce.py).

I can't really tell the difference between my code and theirs that makes mine think it has no parameters to optimize.

**How to make my network have parameters like the linked example?**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your `NetActor` does not directly store any [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/nn.html#torch.nn.Parameter). Moreover, all other layers it eventually uses in `forward` are stored as a *simple* list in `self.nn_layers`.
If you want `self.actor_nn.parameters()` to know that the items stored in the list `self.nn_layers` may contain trainable parameters, you should work with [containers](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/nn.html#containers).
Specifically, making `self.nn_layers` to be a [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/nn.html#torch.nn.ModuleList) instead of a simple list should solve your problem:

```
self.nn_layers = nn.ModuleList()
```

Comment: Thanks! It seemed to.have solved the problem. If I wanted to solve a similar problem in the future, what would be the correct resource to look (beside reading the entire pytorch code and documentation)?

Comment: @Gulzar you can always ask here or in pytorch's forum

Comment: Coming back here 2 years later. Thank you again!

Comment: @Gulzar always a pleasure