# ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list

Tags: pytorch

I create the following simple linear class:

```py
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, K, h=()):
        super().__init__()
        h = (K,)+h+(K,)
        self.layers = [nn.Linear(h1,h2) for h1,h2 in zip(h, h[1:])]

    def forward(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers[:-1]:
            x = F.relu(layer(x))
        return self.layers[-1](x)
```

However, when I try to put the parameters in a optimizer class I get the error `ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list`.

```py
decoder = Decoder(4)
LR = 1e-3
opt = optim.Adam(decoder.parameters(), lr=LR)
```

Is there something I'm doing obviously wrong with the class definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pytorch ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678896/pytorch-valueerror-optimizer-got-an-empty-parameter-list)

Comment: Looking at the other answer now, it is certainly the same issue. However, I think my code is a lot simpler to read. So upto the editors if they want to leave this in or delete this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you store your layers in a regular pythonic list inside your `Decoder`, Pytorch has no way of telling these members of the `self.list` are actually sub modules. Convert this list into pytorch's [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#modulelist) and your problem will be solved

```py
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, K, h=()):
        super().__init__()
        h = (K,)+h+(K,)
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(nn.Linear(h1,h2) for h1,h2 in zip(h, h[1:]))
```

Comment: @NEERAJSWARNKAR if you have a nee question: post it as such, not as a cryptic comment