# RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, gpu

I set my model and data to the same device, but always raise the error like this:

> RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same

The following is my training code, I hope you can answer it.Thanks!

```
def train(train_img_path, train_label_path, pths_path, interval, log_file):

    file_num = len(os.listdir(train_img_path))
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    net = EAST(extractor=extractor, geometry_mode=geometry_mode, pretrained=True)
    net = net.to(device)
    trainset = custom_dataset(train_img_path, train_label_path)
    train_loader = data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                   shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers, drop_last=True)


    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=initial_lr, momentum=momentum, weight_decay=weight_decay_sgd)
    criterion = Loss(weight_geo, weight_angle, geometry_mode="RBOX")

    net.train()
    epoch_loss = 0.
    for epoch in range(max_epoch):
        epoch_time = time.time()
        for i, (img, score_gt, geo_gt, ignored_map) in enumerate(train_loader):
            start_time = time.time()
            img, score_gt, geo_gt, ignored_map = img.to(device), score_gt.to(device),\
                                                 geo_gt.to(device), ignored_map.to(device)

            score_pred, geo_pred = net(img)
            total_loss, score_loss, loss_AABB, loss_angle = criterion(score_pred, geo_pred, score_gt, geo_gt, ignored_map)


            epoch_loss += total_loss.item()

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            total_loss.backward()

            optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your loss function has some internal parameters of its own, therefore you should also

```py
criterion = Loss(weight_geo, weight_angle, geometry_mode="RBOX").to(device)
```

It would be easier to spot the error if you provide a full trace, indicating which line *exactly* caused the error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And your reply inspired me.  The error is not in the loss function, because the list in the model is not put in Sequential.

Comment: @徐乐轩 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57322321/1714410) for example on using containers for submodules.

Comment: Learn so much. `nn.ModuleList` can replace pythonic `list` in Pytorch, and avoid forgetting to use `nn.Sequential`.