# Pytorch nn.DataParallel: RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, dataparallel

I am implementing `nn.DataParallel` class to utilize multiple GPUs on single machine. I have followed some stack overflow questions and answers but still get a simple error. I have no idea why I am getting this error.

**Followed Questions**

1. [RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778066/runtimeerror-input-type-torch-cuda-floattensor-and-weight-type-torch-floatte)
2. [RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013109/runtimeerror-input-type-torch-floattensor-and-weight-type-torch-cuda-floatte)

**Code**

```
# Utilize multiple GPUS
if 'cuda' in device:
    print(device)
    print("using data parallel")
    net = torch.nn.DataParallel(model_ft) # make parallel
    cudnn.benchmark = True

# Transfer the model to GPU
#model_ft = model_ft.to(device)

# # Print model summary
# print('Model Summary:-\n')
# for num, (name, param) in enumerate(model_ft.named_parameters()):
#     print(num, name, param.requires_grad)
# summary(model_ft, input_size=(3, size, size))
# print(model_ft)

# Loss function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Optimizer 
optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Learning rate decay
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_ft, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

# Model training routine 
print("\nTraining:-\n")


def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=30):
    since = time.time()

    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0

    # Tensorboard summary
    writer = SummaryWriter()

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
        print('-' * 10)

        # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
        for phase in ['train', 'valid']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            else:
                model.eval()  # Set model to evaluate mode

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0

            # Iterate over data.
            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                inputs = inputs
                labels = labels

                inputs = inputs.to(device, non_blocking=True)
                labels = labels.to(device, non_blocking=True)

                # zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # forward
                # track history if only in train
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    outputs = model(inputs)
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                    # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                # statistics
                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
            if phase == 'train':
                scheduler.step()

            epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
            epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]

            print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(
                phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))

            # Record training loss and accuracy for each phase
            if phase == 'train':
                writer.add_scalar('Train/Loss', epoch_loss, epoch)
                writer.add_scalar('Train/Accuracy', epoch_acc, epoch)
                writer.flush()
            else:
                writer.add_scalar('Valid/Loss', epoch_loss, epoch)
                writer.add_scalar('Valid/Accuracy', epoch_acc, epoch)
                writer.flush()

            # deep copy the model
            if phase == 'valid' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
                best_acc = epoch_acc
                best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())

        print()

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since
    print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(
        time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
    print('Best val Acc: {:4f}'.format(best_acc))

    # load best model weights
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    return model


# Train the model
model_ft = train_model(model_ft, criterion, optimizer_ft, exp_lr_scheduler,
                       num_epochs=num_epochs)
# Save the entire model
print("\nSaving the model...")
torch.save(model_ft, PATH)
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/coremax/Documents/pytorch-image-classification/train.py", line 263, in <module>
    model_ft = train_model(model_ft, criterion, optimizer_ft, exp_lr_scheduler,
  File "/home2/coremax/Documents/pytorch-image-classification/train.py", line 214, in train_model
    outputs = model(inputs)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/timm/models/resnet.py", line 730, in forward
    x = self.forward_features(x)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/timm/models/resnet.py", line 709, in forward_features
    x = self.conv1(x)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 217, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 463, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 459, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the error, the issue comes from the fact that the input you provided and the model are not the same type, the first one being `torch.cuda.FloatTensor` and the second one `torch.FloatTensor`. As you can see, the issue is that one (the input) in on GPU while the other (the weights of the model) is still on CPU. This issue can be fixed by moving the model to GPU in the beginning. I see that the correct line is commented in the beginning of the code you provided, `model_ft = model_ft.to(device)`. Uncommenting this line should fix this problem.