# Creating a stack of convolutional layers using for loop in forward function of a pytoch class for Residual block

Tags: for-loop, keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

I'm defining a residual block in pytorch for ResNet in which you can input how many convolutional layers you want to have and not necessarily two. This is done through a parameter named nc (number of Convs). The first layer gets ni as the number of input nf number of filters. But from second layer on I put them in a for loop. Here's my code:

```
class ResBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ni, nf,nc=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(ni,nf, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(nf,nf, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.conv1x1 = nn.Conv2d(ni, nf, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.nc = nc    
    def forward(self, x): 
        y = self.conv1(x)
        for i in range(self.nc-1):
            y = self.conv2(y)
            print(torch.mean(y))            
        return self.conv1x1(x) + y
```

But no matter what value I give to nc, it always returns 2 convs with kernel size 3. I'm not sure if for loop can really do this job in pytorch but it was working when I used functional API in Keras. Could anyone help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, printing a `nn.Module` object is often misleading. When you print, you get:

```
# for ni=3, nf=16
ResBlock(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2))
  (conv2): Conv2d(16, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
  (conv1x1): Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
)
```

because these are the only 3 `Module`s you registered in the `__init__` of the `ResBlock`.

The actual forward can (and in your case will) be doing something completely different.

Comment: I see! So how can I fix this? I can't use for loop then and I would have to do it manually like self.conv2(self.conv2(self.conv2(...)))?

Answer (score 0):

I faced something similar recently. I did not want to use `nn.Sequential`. When I print the model it did not show the operations I defined using loop in forward function. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097924/how-to-create-variable-names-in-loop-for-layers-in-pytorch-neural-network) worked for me.

I did not use loop in `__init__` function to define the layers when defining the model. Only stored the layer in a variable then in `forward` function looped over it. This resulted in `print(model)` not showing layers added using for loop defined in forward function. Solution was to use [nn.ModuleList](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html#torch.nn.ModuleList).

This code below shows wrong results,

### Code

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_units, hidden_units, hidden_layer_count, output_units):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_layer_count = hidden_layer_count

        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=input_units, out_features=hidden_units)
        self.hidden_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_units, out_features=hidden_units)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_units, out_features=output_units)

    def forward(self, item):
        x = self.input_layer(item)
        
        for i in range(self.hidden_layer_count):
            x = self.hidden_layer(x)

        output = self.output_layer(x)
        return output
```

```
my_model = MyModel(input_units=2, hidden_units=128, hidden_layer_count=7, output_units=3)
print(my_model)
```

#### Output

```
MyModel(
  (input_layer): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=128, bias=True)
  (hidden_layer): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=128, bias=True)
  (output_layer): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=3, bias=True)
)
```

This code below defines the layers in loop with `nn.ModuleList` and the in forward function those layer are traversed. This gives expected result.

### Code

```
class MyModel2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_units, hidden_units, hidden_layer_count, output_units):
        super(MyModel2, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_layer_count = hidden_layer_count

        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=input_units, out_features=hidden_units)
        self.hidden_layers = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(
            in_features=hidden_units, out_features=hidden_units
            ) for i in range(hidden_layer_count)])
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_units, out_features=output_units)

    def forward(self, item):
        x = self.input_layer(item)
        
        for hidden_layer in self.hidden_layers:
            x = hidden_layer(x)

        output = self.output_layer(x)
        return output
```

```
my_model2 = MyModel2(input_units=2, hidden_units=128, hidden_layer_count=7, output_units=3)
print(my_model2)
```

#### Output

```
MyModel2(
  (input_layer): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=128, bias=True)
  (hidden_layers): ModuleList(
    (0): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=128, bias=True)
    (1): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=128, bias=True)
    (2): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=128, bias=True)
    (3): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=128, bias=True)
    (4): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=128, bias=True)
    (5): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=128, bias=True)
    (6): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=128, bias=True)
  )
  (output_layer): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=3, bias=True)
)
```