# Is there any thing like 'TensorList’ in pytorch?

Tags: list, pytorch, tensor

I would like to put some tensor in a list, and I know if I would like to put `nn.Module` class into a list, I must use `ModuleList` to wrap that list.
So, Is there anything like 'TensorList’ in pytorch, that I must use to wrap the list containing tensors?

Comment: No! Tensorlist does not exist in pytorch.

Answer (score 2):

What are these tensors? Are these tensors parameters of your `nn.Module`? If so, you need to use the proper [container](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10.0/nn.html#containers).
For example, using [`nn.ParameterList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10.0/generated/torch.nn.ParameterList.html#torch.nn.ParameterList). This way calling your module's `.paramters()` methods will yield these tensors as well. Otherwise you'll get errors like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54678896/1714410).

Comment: If I would like to use `torch.eye` or `torch.zeros` in the `nn.Module`. Whether I need to use `self.register_buffer` to wrap those function or not?

Comment: I use `torch.chunk` to split a big tensor into many small tensor and store them in a list. When I need to calculate them, I use List Comprehensions like `[torch.mm(x, self.W) for x in model_input]`. Is it a correct operation to deal with those tensors (containing the parameters and model inputs) of my `nn.Module`